# How to enable garbage collection info in local mode?

Tags: apache-spark

I am following Spark's [tuning guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#garbage-collection-tuning) for collecting JVM's garbage collection information. I added the following line to `spark-defaults.conf` hoping to get them.

```
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions  -verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

I do not see any GC related info in the driver output in local mode. How to enable them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions` instead.

Since you work in `local` mode, the driver and executors are the same, i.e. there is only one JVM that hosts the driver and the one executor.